# Powershell get-childitem works different with long-path prefix (\\?\)

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, unc, get-childitem

I have different results in these two cases:

- case 1: `Get-ChildItem -Path "\\?\UNC\very\long\path"`
- case 2: `Get-ChildItem -Path "\\very\long\path"`

If the long path is less than 260 characters long, I have diferent results.

- case 1: Zero child items returned.
- case 2: all the child items expected.

For getting same results, I should do different in case 1:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\?\UNC\very\long\path\*"
```

Why this difference?
I use `\\?\UNC` prefix because the fullpath is variable and I do not know it.

Perhaps I should use `\*` wildcard in both cases?

Comment: "If the long path is less than 260 characters long, I have diferent results." - can you tell us how the results differ?

Comment: In first case I have no results: zero. In second case a can see the list of all the subdirectories.

Comment: This is a common question about windows itself and long paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing **a *bug* in *Windows PowerShell*** that surfaces when you pass *literal* paths (non-wildcard) paths using a long-path prefix (`\\?\` for local paths, `\\?\Unc\` for UNC paths) to the (possibly positionally implied) `-Path` parameter. See the bottom section for details.

To work around it, **use the `-LiteralPath` parameter** instead, which is the right thing to do for non-[wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) paths anyway:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath \\?\UNC\server1\share1\very\long\path
```

---

Note:

- [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) is no longer affected, because it has *implicit* support for long paths; that is, **you don't need the long-path prefixes anymore**.
- However, these prefixes should still be *accepted*, which is something that is *partially broken* up to at least PowerShell 7.3.5 - see [GitHub issue #10805](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10805)

---

**Windows PowerShell bug details:**

The bug surfaces when you pass a non-wildcard *root* path that has a long-path prefix to `-Path`, which applies to both using the local and the UNC forms of the prefix, though the symptoms differ:

```bash
# UNC root path: 
# NO OUTPUT
Get-ChildItem -Path \\?\UNC\server1\share1

# LOCAL root path:
# -> SPURIOUS ERROR "Cannot retrieve Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. ..."
Get-ChildItem -Path \\?\C:\
```

*Appending at least one additional path component* makes the problem go away; e.g.:

```bash
# Both OK, due to addition of another path component.
Get-ChildItem -Path \\?\UNC\server1\share1\subfolder
Get-ChildItem -Path \\?\C:\Windows
```

Curiously, however, the *local* form doesn't support *wildcards* on the level of the drive *root*:

```bash
# !! NO OUTPUT
Get-ChildItem -Path \\?\C:\*

# By contrast, wildcards DO work with the UNC prefix at the 
# top-level of the share
Get-ChildItem -Path \\?\UNC\server1\share1\*
```

As an aside:

- Irrespective of whether a long-path prefix is used or not, wildcard matching of UNC *share* names is unsupported and quietly returns *nothing*.
- That is, you cannot use `*` in order to discover available shares on a given server; something like `Get-ChildItem -Path \\server1\*` or `Get-ChildItem -Path \\?UNC\server1\*` never produces output.

Comment: Thank you, very clear. I edit the question title, because the bug is with long-path prefix, not with unc notation as I first wrote.